# Energy absorbed by a medium if X-rays pass through it

Tags: visible-light, x-rays

Obviously light-matter interactions are extremely complicated, but I’m trying to get a general estimate.

Say I have a beam of X-rays, passing through a medium - say water - of a finite thickness and width. These X-rays will quickly get absorbed after a few micrometers, and re-emitted at a lower wavelength. This will happen millions of times, and the beam will be dispersed. After millions of absorptions and re-emissions, the photons will end up at a wavelength where the attenuation length is quite long, and they exit the medium.

How much energy would be deposited by this beam? I’m having trouble even beginning to model the problem. My initial hunch was to assume that the beam stays coherent through the medium, photons keep traveling in the same direction, depositing energy at every interaction. But photons are absorbed and emitted at random directions.

EDIT: To clarify my question, here's an example:
I have a 10W X-ray laser passing through a cubic meter of water (1m on each side). How many watts ends up heating the water, and how many end up passing through the medium? I'm also more concerned about how you would solve the problem rather than the actual answer.

Comment: Do you know exactly the amount of energy involved in the initial beam interactions?  If not, why do you care about whether the energy comes from the initial xray photon or a later, lower-energy one?  I would think you'd just measure the total energy absorbed from the beam.

Comment: @BowlOfRed My question is basically: I have a 10W X-ray laser passing through a cubic meter of water (1m on each side). How many watts ends up heating the water, and how many end up passing through the medium?

Comment: How accurate an answer is needed? What energy should count?  For example, some fraction will come back out the front of the volume. It would also be useful to know the energy (range or spectrum) of the beam.

Comment: @BobJacobsen I'm more curious as to how you would solve the problem - doesn't need to be too accurate, just a decent approximation. If it's easiest to just do a beam of 1 keV photons go ahead.

Comment: If you want better than a 10% answer, I’d do a simulation. Hence the questions. There are a lot of effects that all enter at that scale.

Comment: Given that x-rays will pass through large parts of you just fine indicates that your description above is fatally flawed.

Comment: Also, just saying "10W" doesn't mean much.  More important is the spectral power of the beam.  Higher frequencies will be more penetrating.

Comment: http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/chap3.html and https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ComTab/water.html are useful when you know the power at the different photon energy levels.

Comment: http://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/atten2.html  type in H20, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150546/why-dont-x-rays-travel-through-water